# Move file from Tails to MacOS without connecting to the Internet?

Tags: osx, tails-os

I have generated a file offline on Tails that I want to move to another OS without connecting to the Internet. It might have been better to use another Live OS in hindsight.

I guessed that the best way to do this would be to use persistent storage on Tails.

But I have not been able to figure out nor find information on how to access the persistent storage from MacOS, I have only read that it is possible.

Comment: Is a pen-drive available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply mount another USB disk and write the files to that disk and then move them to your Mac manually. Another option, which would hurt your secrecy a bit as it can leave a trace on the host system, is mounting the host systems internal hard drive through Nautilus in Tails.

Here is a link to how to mount the internal hard disks:

https://tails.boum.org/doc/encryption_and_privacy/your_data_wont_be_saved_unless_explicitly_asked/index.en.html